# How do I manage MarkLogic REST endpoint extension versions using gradle?

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I'm extending the REST API in MarkLogic and managing my development and deployment using gradle. By default, my endpoint looks like this (note **v1**):

```
http://localhost:8005/v1/resources/my_endpoint
```

If I change my endpoint implementation, how do I expose the new version as **v2** and keep the original (**v1**) for backward compatibility so that I have

```
http://localhost:8005/v2/resources/my_endpoint
```

using gradle? I don't see any way to annotate version in my gradle config files. I've been searching MarkLogic's gradle wiki and haven't found an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

The REST API unfortunately doesn't allow for what you want - see [https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/config/resources/[name]](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/config/resources/%5Bname%5D) . You can specify a version as optional metadata on your extension, but that will not change the URL - it's still going to be "/v1/resources/my_endpoint".

You however can achieve this if you customize the default XML rewriter that MarkLogic uses for a REST API app server - see https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/XMLrewriter .

Comment: Thanks for your help @rjrudin.
So as a strategy, I could have a rewriter rewrite an incoming url `/api/v2/my_endpoint` to `/v1/resources/v2_my_endpoint` and achieve what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Right - you can achieve pretty much anything via the declarative XML rewriter. I usually use the existing rewriter rules for examples when I'm customizing it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to meet requirement using [a declarative rewriter](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/XMLrewriter#id_73388) as @rjrudin suggested.

I started by copying `<MarkLogic install dir>\Modules\MarkLogic\rest-api\rewriter.xml` to `api-rewriter.xml`, modifying the new file, and updating my rest api server `Url Rewriter` value (via Admin console).

Then I added the following declarations:

```
<match-path matches="^/api">
    <match-method any-of="GET">
        <match-path matches="/(v\d+\.\d+)/([\w|\-]+)/(\d+)">
            <set-query-param name="name">$1_$2</set-query-param>
            <set-query-param name="rs:id">$3</set-query-param>
            <dispatch>/MarkLogic/rest-api/endpoints/resource-service-query.xqy</dispatch>
        </match-path>
        <match-path matches="/(v\d+\.\d+)/(\w+)">
            <set-query-param name="name">$1_$2</set-query-param>
            <dispatch>/MarkLogic/rest-api/endpoints/resource-service-query.xqy</dispatch>
        </match-path>
    </match-method>
</match-path>
```

I create resource implementations using `ml-gradle` with names that look like this: `v2.0_ping.sjs`. So now I can use urls like this:

```
http://{{host}}:{{port}}/api/v2.0/ping
```

that resolve to

```
/MarkLogic/rest-api/endpoints/resource-service-query.xqy?name=v2.0_ping
```

Comment: Note that you can load that rewriter by storing it under src/main/ml-modules and configuring your app server - via a file under src/main/ml-config/servers - to reference it. That avoids the manual step of adjusting the rewriter URL via the Admin UI.

Comment: Thanks @rjrudin! That was my next question :-)